# Can somebody fix a miss-spell in a command?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing

[Why can't I set screen brightness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84998/why-cant-i-set-screen-brightness)

The last line says `sudo update-grup` and it needs to say `sudo update-grub`.

I cannot change or propose a one letter change but it is incorrect.

Comment: Remember that you can use a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Correction has been made.

You should be able to hit the edit link and submit a change yourself.  It will be peer-reviewed before appearing on the website.

Comment: Tried that but it was considered a one character change would then I could not pass go.  thanks